# javascript array text substitution

Tags: javascript

I have an Array - I would like to merge and replace the '%' with values from the 2nd, 3rd elements

The Array looks like this

```
[0] = "Hi may name is '%s' and my brother is '%d'"
[1] = "John"
[2] = "David"
```

Id like to return a single string like :
"Hi my name is John and my brother is David"

Any ideas?  thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your attempts at solving this problem? Also, why `%d` since both values are strings?

Comment: @Jon Are the single quotes supposed to be replaced as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this works: http://jsfiddle.net/4ax7mvL4/5/

```
var a = [];
a[0] = "Hi may name is '%s' and my brother is '%d'";
a[1] = "John";
a[2] = "David";
var final = a[0];

for(var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
    final = final.replace(/%[sd]/, a[i]);
}
alert(final);
```

But I'm sure there are people out there that could optimize it and make it nicer looking :)

Comment: why use a `for in` loop with an array and what's with the `continue` after the replace?

Comment: Okay took all that into account.

Comment: Like I said, people are better than me at this, but I thought I'd give it a go :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a C style `printf` implementation in JavaScript, you can try using [sprintf for JavaScript](https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js), from its documentation:

Its prototype:

```
string sprintf(string format , [mixed arg1 [, mixed arg2 [ ,...]]])
```

A type specifier that can be any of:

- % — yields a literal % character
- b — yields an integer as a binary number
- c — yields an integer as the character with that ASCII value
- d or i — yields an integer as a signed decimal number
- e — yields a float using scientific notation
- and so on.

The [`vsprintf`](https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js#javascript-vsprintf) version also accepts the inputs in an array form:

```
vsprintf("Hi may name is '%s' and my brother is '%d'", ["John", "David"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your <head> tag.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var arr = [ 
        "Hi may name is '%s' and my brother is '%d'",
        "John",
        "David" ];
    var txt = arr[0].replace("%s", arr[1]).replace("%d", arr[2]);

    alert(txt);
});
</script>
```

please take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/oa8ykLkr/

Comment: Not a very reusable ‘solution’.

Comment: Should be single quotes... sorry